# Iterate over indices with constant sum in Python

Tags: python, loops, iteration, python-itertools

I am working with polynomials and have to perform some operation where my looping variables have a sum inferior to some constant `d`.
Right now I have

```
for i in range(0, d):
    for j in range(i, d):
        for k in range(j, d):
```

which seems a bit ugly to me.
Is there some function, probably in `itertools`, allowing me to iterate `for i, j, k in foo(d)` ?

Comment: Given the dependencies between the ranges, I don't think there is anything specific to help.

Answer (score 3):

You can write your own.  Here's a brute force way for 3 variables:

```
def constant_sum(s):
    for i in range(s+1):
        for j in range(s-i+1):
            k = s - i - j
            yield i,j,k

def inferior_sum(s):
    for i in range(s+1):
        for j in range(s+1):
            if i+j >= s:
                break
            for k in range(s+1):
                if i+j+k < s:
                    yield i,j,k
                else:
                    break

for i,j,k in constant_sum(3):
    print(i,j,k)
print()
for i,j,k in inferior_sum(3):
    print(i,j,k)
```

Output:

```
0 0 3
0 1 2
0 2 1
0 3 0
1 0 2
1 1 1
1 2 0
2 0 1
2 1 0
3 0 0

0 0 0
0 0 1
0 0 2
0 1 0
0 1 1
0 2 0
1 0 0
1 0 1
1 1 0
2 0 0
```

Here are recursive versions that can do any number of variables(n) for any sum(s)...lightly tested:

```
def constant_sum(n,s):
    if n == 1:
        yield [s]
    else:
        for i in range(s+1):
            for r in constant_sum(n-1,s-i):
                yield [i] + r

def inferior_sum(n,s):
    if n == 1:
        for i in range(s):
            yield [i]
    else:
        for i in range(s):
            for r in inferior_sum(n-1,s-i):
                yield [i] + r

for x in constant_sum(3,3):
    print(*x)
print()
for x in inferior_sum(3,3):
    print(*x)
```

Output:

```
0 0 3
0 1 2
0 2 1
0 3 0
1 0 2
1 1 1
1 2 0
2 0 1
2 1 0
3 0 0

0 0 0
0 0 1
0 0 2
0 1 0
0 1 1
0 2 0
1 0 0
1 0 1
1 1 0
2 0 0
```

Comment: +1 I really like the recursive approach. You could do that with tuples as well to maintain the user friendly interface (also slightly faster).

Answer (score 2):

The itertools/functional way would be something like:

```
from itertools import product
inferior_sum3 = filter(lambda x: sum(x)<3, product(range(4),range(4),range(4)))
for permu in inferior_sum3:
    print(permu)
```

Output:

```
(0, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 1)
(0, 0, 2)
(0, 1, 0)
(0, 1, 1)
(0, 2, 0)
(1, 0, 0)
(1, 0, 1)
(1, 1, 0)
(2, 0, 0)
```